# How check if image exists in apple watch app

Tags: watchkit

How I check for image existence inside the watch app bundle (not the iphone  extension app).
I have tried loading the image using 
    UIImage(named: imageName)
but this method is to load the image from the app extension inside the iphone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loading the image, you have to tick the watch app and watchkit extension target when you drag some images to your project, After that you can load the image.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check if an image file is included in the watch app bundle, you'll have to go to

1) project settings

2) click on the **WatchKit App target**

3) click on **Build Phases** tab

4) look for it in the **Copy Bundle Resources** section or type in the name of the image at the search box

Comment: I need to do it in runtime (while the application is running)